# Copying objects from plist file to another plist file

Tags: ios, plist

So in my last question I tried to figure out what should I use, Plist or Core data or sqlight and I've decided that I'll try all of them to improve my skills.
So I've started reading about plist and the way they work and i'm not really sure about a few things. The app purpose I'm writing is to give the user a few lists of different songs from different genre from plist files that looks like this:

[image: pic]

The user will be abale to choose what songs he likes and those will be added to a new list.
Can I copy songs (a simple Dictionary in a plist file in my case) and create a new plist out of them. Or should I use a stack or an array to push the songs in and use a table view as an outlet? Eventually I want the user to have saved playlists he created.

I'm curious to know if something that I've suggested won't work and what is a more elegant approach for doing so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
NSString *plistFileName = [[self documentPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Original.plist"];


if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistFileName]) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFileName];
}
```

Show this data in table view and ask the user to select the songs. Save the selected one in another dictionary as,

```
    NSDictionary *savedPlayListDict = //saved songs

    NSString *fileName = [[self documentPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SavedList.plist"];
    [savedPlayListDict writeToFile: fileName atomically:YES];
```

Or you can create your own model classes for saving the key value pairs in dictionary and use that to represent each row of the table.

For eg:- `Song` can be a model object with properties as, `UIImage *pic`, `NSInteger number` and `NSString *name`. You can add these Song objects in an array and populate your table view, using this array. Once user has selected the list, you can convert the saved list into a dictionary and save to plist as shown above.

These are just a few options. You can do it a lot of different ways.

Comment: From your experience , isn't plist a cleaner way to save the songs data than writing all the info in the code as models?

Comment: Model is just a way to represent the data in memory. plist is used to persist the data. Both are different. When you want to write to the disc, you can use plist. Whenever you are reading it back, convert it to model objects. That should make your job easier. When you dont want to persist the data, you can just use model objects in an array. But if you want to store it somewhere and use it later, you might need plist or coredata.

Comment: Maybe you know a good reference \ tutorial on how to use model objects. Pushing & popping etc'?

Comment: @MikaStern, Check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1. They are using ScaryBugDoc as a model object for populating the table. Instead of that you can use songs as your model class.

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thanks a lot!